# Type '{ description: String; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IOrderFormWithReactProps': context, siteUrlts(2769)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, typescript2.0, react-typescript

i dont know why this error occurs. it shows Type '{ description: String; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IOrderFormWithReactProps': context, siteUrlts(2769)

```
***OrderFormreactWithWebpart.ts file:***


import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart, WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'OrderFormWithReactWebPartStrings';
import OrderFormWithReact from './components/OrderFormWithReact';
import { IOrderFormWithReactProps } from './components/IOrderFormWithReactProps';
import { description } from 'OrderFormWithReactWebPartStrings';
export interface IOrderFormWithReactWebPartProps {
  description: String;
  context: WebPartContext;
  siteUrl: any;
}


export default class OrderFormWithReactWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IOrderFormWithReactWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IOrderFormWithReactProps> = React.createElement(
      OrderFormWithReact,
      {
        description: this.properties.description
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }


***IOrderFormWithReactProps.ts file***

import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface IOrderFormWithReactProps {
description: String;
context: WebPartContext;
siteUrl: any;

}
```

this is the interface for that props file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OrderFormWithReact` requires `description`, `context` and `siteUrl`. You are only giving it `description`.

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IOrderFormWithReactProps> = React.createElement(
  OrderFormWithReact,
  {
    description: this.properties.description
  }
);
```

Try this. It just passes the properties of `OrderFormWithReactWebPart` on to `OrderFormWithReact`. (So it requires that the properties of `OrderFormWithReactWebPart` include `context` and `siteUrl`.)

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IOrderFormWithReactProps> = React.createElement(
  OrderFormWithReact,
  this.properties
);
```